# Elasticsearch order of execution of query with aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and while constructing queries I had some thoughts and questions about performance issues and order of execution.

Let's assume I have documents persisted in Elasticsearch for the past 3 years and I am only interested in aggregations preformed on these documents. For the sake of the example the documents have a timestamp field and a user field. I wanted to know what happens under the hood if I perform the following query:

```
{
    "query": {},
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "documents_by_user": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min_time": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "timestamp"
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is Elasticsearch going to first fetch all the documents indexed for the past 3 years, then perform the aggregations and finally fetch only 10 buckets? If so these kinds of queries should be avoided...
Or is Elasticsearch "smart" enough to build the buckets on the fly in some way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any constraints in the query part, yes, all the documents will be taken into account for the aggregation, but that's not an issue as that's what ES is good at.

The way it's working is that `user` will be aggregated on each shard of your index and the top 25 ([explanation why 25](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-shard-size)) of each shard are going to be collected and reordered once again and only the top 10 will be considered.

Then for each of the top 10 users, the minimum timestamp will be returned in each user bucket.

Comment: Wow thanks for your answer, it is good to know that these kinds of queries can be performed without harming the performance! A few follow up questions:

1. If I would have added constraints in my query, would the performance be better?
2. How bad would the performance be affected the more I increase the "size" field in the "terms" agg?
3. Is there any reference you could point me at for further information on this subject?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Yes, because there would be less documents to aggregate 2. That's hard to tell because it depends on hardware factors and your volume of data, but yes, if you increase the size too much, performance will degrade for sure. 3. The link I added in my answer contains all there is to know on the terms aggregation and how it works.